# How to display Block content on menu click?

Tags: 7, navigation, blocks

I want to display a block below a menu item (like a dropdown) when I click on the menu item. Specifically I want to use this way to display the search block when I click on the my search menu item.

Any suggestions about how to do this?

Comment: Please avoid asking question for modules as it is not as per policy of DA. Please Refer: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. Please modify your question, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Install the [Menu Attach Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attach_block) module

> Menu Attach Block allows you to embed blocks in menu items. You may choose to
>   replace a menu item entirely with a block, or keep the menu link and embed the
>   block after it in the wrapper element.